# reactjsでstateの変更ができない

Tags: javascript, reactjs

react中で1つの関数内で

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

のようにし、itemを[]で初期化し、

```
useEffect(() => {
  http.getItems().then((data) => {
    setItems(data);
  });
}, []);
```

で、jsonを取得しております。その後同じ関数内において

```
const itemList = function () {
  const list = items.map((item) => {
    <div className="foo" key={item.id}>
      <Item
        title={item.title}
        price={item.price}
        URL={item.url}
      />
    </div>;
  });
  return list;
};
```

とし、最終的には

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="container App-main">
      <div className="row">{itemList()}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

のようにして表示させたいのですが、実際のページには何も表示されておりません。
React Developer Toolsでは

> hooks
> state:
> [{...},{...},{...}]

と表記され、きちんとitemsには配列が入っているようです。
警告として

> Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function  array-callback-return

が出ているため

> const itemList = function () {

のところでうまく処理できていないように思うのですが、
どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。
以上のコードはまとめると次の通りです。

```
import HttpService from "./service";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Item from "./item";
const http = new HttpService();

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    http.getItems().then((data) => {
      setItems(data);
    });
  }, []);

  const itemList = function () {
    const list = items.map((item) => {
      <div className="foo" key={item.id}>
        <Item title={item.title} price={item.price} URL={item.url} />
      </div>;
    });
    return list;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container App-main">
        <div className="row">{itemList()}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

またitem.jsは以下の通りです。

```
import React from "react";

function Item(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={props.url}></img>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <p>Price: {props.price}</p>
        <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">
          Add
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Item;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  const itemList = function () {
    const list = items.map((item) => {
      <div className="foo" key={item.id}>
        <Item title={item.title} price={item.price} URL={item.url} />
      </div>;
    });
    return list;
  };
```

`items`の配列を`.map()`でReact Elementに変換してると思いますが、`.map()`に渡しているアロー関数で値がreturnされていないため、変換できていません。

以下の様にreturnするように修正してみてください。

```js
  const itemList = function () {
    const list = items.map((item) => {
      return (
        <div className="foo" key={item.id}>
          <Item title={item.title} price={item.price} URL={item.url} />
        </div>
      );
    });
    return list;
  };
```

また、アロー関数はreturnが1行だけの場合、`{}`と`return`を省略できますので、以下の様に書くこともできます。

```js
  const itemList = function () {
    const list = items.map((item) => (
      <div className="foo" key={item.id}>
        <Item title={item.title} price={item.price} URL={item.url} />
      </div>
    ));
    return list;
  };
```

Comment: アロー関数について理解できていなかったようです。丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます。