# Next.js内のJSXでmapで二重ループしたい。

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-jsx, next.js

ブログを作成していて、記事の背景をループするごとに切り替えていきたくて下記のコード書いたのですが、上手く動作しないです。
`map()`を使用するのはJSXはレンダーするのに配列にして返す必要があるため、`map()`を二重にしてカラーを適用した要素を返す事で上手くいくと思っていましたが、画面に何も表示されないです。
教えて頂けないでしょうか、お願いします。

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { getPostsData } from '../lib/posts'
import { getSortedPostsData } from '../lib/posts'
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Article } from '../types/Article'
import Layout from '../components/layout'

export default function Home({ 
  sortedPostData,
  colorPattern
}: {
  sortedPostData: Article[],
  colorPattern: string[]
}) {
  return (
    <Layout home>
      <div className="">
        <Head>
          <title>Hello</title>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <ul>
          {sortedPostData.map(({ id, title }) => (
            colorPattern.map((color) => {
              <li className={color} key={id}>
                <Link href={`/posts/${id}`}>
                  <a>{title}</a>
                </Link>
              </li>
            })
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const allPostsData = await getPostsData() //記事を {[...],[...]...}こんな感じで取得する。
  const sortedPostData = await getSortedPostsData(allPostsData)//上記の記事を書いた日順に並べ換える
  const pattern = ["bg-blue", "bg-blue-light", "bg-gray", "bg-earth-light"]; 
  const max = sortedPostData.length;
  const colorPattern = Array(max).fill("").map((_, i) => pattern[i % 4]);//　記事の数だけ背景色を生成する。
  return {
    props: {
      sortedPostData,
      colorPattern 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ぱっと見ですが、`colorPattern.map()` に渡しているアロー関数でreturnがされていないように見えますね。参考: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75455/reactjs%e3%81%a7state%e3%81%ae%e5%a4%89%e6%9b%b4%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84/75466#75466 。それを修正しても直らない場合、別に問題がありそうですが。

Comment: `const` 打ち込むだけでVScodeで `A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.` 出るので上手くいきません。

Comment: `> const 打ち込むだけで` では実装を修正した上で新たに出たエラーの詳細を書くように質問を更新したほうが良さそうですね。どこにどのようなコードを書こうとしてそのエラーが出たのかコメントだけでは読み取れませんでしたので。

Comment: あと2重ループを回すこと自体が目的になってしまっているように見えます。実現されたいことを考えると、このようなコードでよさそうな気がしますが、いかがでしょうか？: https://jsfiddle.net/cf50uLqs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

類似質問: [reactjsでstateの変更ができない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/75455/3068)

> ```js
>         <ul>
>           {sortedPostData.map(({ id, title }) => (
>             colorPattern.map((color) => {
>               <li className={color} key={id}>
>                 <Link href={`/posts/${id}`}>
>                   <a>{title}</a>
>                 </Link>
>               </li>
>             })
>           ))}
>         </ul>
> ```

コメントにも書きましたが、2重ループの内側のループ(`colorPattern.map()`)で値が return されていません。

`.map()`に渡すアロー関数を以下の様に直してください。

```js
colorPattern.map((color) => { return (<li ...(中略)... </li>); })
```

**コード例**

```js
// {} を使用したアロー関数で値を返す場合、明示的に return が必要
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {[1, 2, 3].map(n => (
        ["a", "b", "c"].map(s => {
          return (
            <li key={`${n}${s}`}>
              {n}{s}
            </li>
          );
        })
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Home />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

また、アロー関数は return 1文だけの場合、 `{}` と `return` を省略できますので、以下の様に書くこともできます。

```js
colorPattern.map((color) => (<li ...(中略)... </li>))
```

外側のループの `sortedPostData.map(({ id, title }) => ())` ではこちらの記法が使われているので、特に修正や変更は不要です。

アロー関数式 - JavaScript | MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

---

ただ、前記の **コード例** の実行結果からも分かると思いますが、
この修正を行っても2重ループでReact Elementを生成しているので
結果的に以下のようなDOMが生成されます。

```html
<li className="bg-blue"        key="1"><Link href="/posts/1"><a>title1</a></Link></li>
<li className="bg-blue-light"  key="1"><Link href="/posts/1"><a>title1</a></Link></li>
<li className="bg-gray"        key="1"><Link href="/posts/1"><a>title1</a></Link></li>
<li className="bg-earth-light" key="1"><Link href="/posts/1"><a>title1</a></Link></li>

<li className="bg-blue"        key="2"><Link href="/posts/2"><a>title2</a></Link></li>
<li className="bg-blue-light"  key="2"><Link href="/posts/2"><a>title2</a></Link></li>
<li className="bg-gray"        key="2"><Link href="/posts/2"><a>title2</a></Link></li>
<li className="bg-earth-light" key="2"><Link href="/posts/2"><a>title2</a></Link></li>

<li className="bg-blue"        key="3"><Link href="/posts/3"><a>title3</a></Link></li>
<li className="bg-blue-light"  key="3"><Link href="/posts/3"><a>title3</a></Link></li>
<li className="bg-gray"        key="3"><Link href="/posts/3"><a>title3</a></Link></li>
<li className="bg-earth-light" key="3"><Link href="/posts/3"><a>title3</a></Link></li>
...
```

これは質問者さんが求めている結果ではないはずです。

(兄弟 node 間で key が重複しているのも問題ですが、それは置いといて)

例えば以下のようなコードにすれば、期待通りの結果が得られるかと思います。

```
const pattern = ["bg-blue", "bg-blue-light", "bg-gray", "bg-earth-light"]; 

function getColorClassFromIndex(index: number): string {
  return pattern[index % pattern.length];
}

export default function Home({ sortedPostData }: { sortedPostData: Article[] }) {
  return (
    <Layout home>
      <div className="">
        <Head>
          <title>Hello</title>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <ul>
          {sortedPostData.map(({ id, title }, index) => (
            <li className={getColorClassFromIndex(index)} key={id}>
              <Link href={`/posts/${id}`}>
                <a>{title}</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

整数を4で割った余りが `0, 1, 2, 3, 0, ...` で循環するように、任意の整数nで割った余りは 0 ～ n-1 で循環しますので、これを元に配列から値を取り出せば、配列内の値を循環しながら参照できます。

また、`Array.prototype.map()` に渡す関数の第二引数には、配列の index が渡されますので、いま配列のどの index の値が渡されているのか知ることができます。

Array.prototype.map() - JavaScript | MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

---

外部(props)からclassの一覧を渡していますが、li に正しい class を指定しないと意図した通りに表示されないと思いますので、この class 一覧と Home コンポーネントには「強い依存関係」があるため、外部から渡さなくてもいいのかな、と感じました。

もちろん外部から渡すように実装しても良いですが、使用者が使い方を気を付けなければいけないコンポーネントやAPIというのは良くない設計の一例だと思います。

---

質問とは無関係ですが、もし `<Link>` のコンポーネントが a タグのDOMを生成するなら、`{title}`を囲んでる a タグは不要な気がしました。

実際に生成されたDOMが `<a href="/post/id"> <a>title</a> </a>` になっていた場合は修正を検討してみてください。

```js
<Link href={`/posts/${id}`}>
  {title}
</Link>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの意図を汲み取って回答して下さり、ありがとうございます。上手く動作しました。

Comment: よかったです～！